# CSS3 animation image quality on scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have downscaled images that onclick scale to the images original size. The image quality is very poor when the images are in a scaled down state. Any way to improve this?

(Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w9o2chmn/7/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var zoomed = false;
    var card = $("#card0");
    card.click(function() {
        zoomFunction();
    });

    function zoomFunction() {
        if (zoomed) { //card flipped so front is invisible and back is visible. 
            zoomed = false;
            card.removeClass('zoom');
        } else { //card not flipped so front is visible and back is invisible
            zoomed = true;
            card.addClass('zoom');
        }
    };
});
```

```css
html {height: 100%;}
.zoom {transform: scale(1.0);}
img {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<img id="card0"  src="http://valtterilaine.bitbucket.org/png/vihainen.png">
```

Comment: Not really...no, other than using SVG images,

Comment: Do you need to do that with css? Solution with jquery would give you better image quality. For example https://jsfiddle.net/w9o2chmn/15/

Answer (score 1):

- add `backface-visibility: hidden` https://jsfiddle.net/w9o2chmn/12/
- use `zoom:50%` instead of `transform: scale(0.5)`: https://jsfiddle.net/w9o2chmn/11/

both fixes are only works in chrome!

Comment: Is there anyway to use it in an animation?

Comment: That's a trick and doesn't work. The quality still poor. Please, avoid non standard properties that only works with XX, we need to achieve a free world wide web, not a chrome only world. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

Comment: I pretty much need to run it on all modern browsers, including mobile

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following properties for the img tag. They may help, depending on the image.

```
img{
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          /* Firefox */
    image-rendering:   -o-crisp-edges;          /* Opera   */
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Webkit  */
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   /* IE      */

    will-change: transform; // will consume additional memory
}
```

The `will-change:transform` property will make scaled down images look better on it's own on Chrome due to the work being done on the GPU and, typically, improve speed (smoothness) of the transform animation. It will, however, take up device memory which might be a concern if there are a lot of cards, especially on mobile.

**Another, more "guaranteed"** solution would be to use the performant `scale` transition only while animating, and when the animation completes, remove the scale property and set the `width` to half of the original width.

The basic algorithm for scaling down would be, for example:

1. Set a transition that only affects transform (`transition:transform 1s;`)
2. Scale the image down with `transform:scale(0.5)`. The image now looks bad.
3. Remove the `transition:transform 1s;` property so that transforms are instant, then remove the `transform:scale(0.5)` property. The image now looks good but is of original size.
4. Set the width of the image to half at the same time the scale property is removed, so that the width change is invisible. The image is now half of the size and looks good.

This is better illustrated by the following modified [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KasparasAnusauskas/rcj9sp9n/)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a thumbnail and set an onclick to load your larger image. You can format both the thumbnail and regular image separately this way using CSS if you don't wanna do it in jquery. But even more simple would be to save two versions previously edited.

Answer (score -1):

It might be better to take the image and resize it in any photo editing application. I have found that if i need to resize the image and dont want a grainy and pixelated photo to do it in a third party app. If you want a transition when the images are clicked or hovered you could you the original image and make a second copy of the image in the desired size. Then, you can use another transition so when the photo is clicked it transforms the size of the image while looking normal even though it is two different images.